# Multiple boot system results in slow boot time

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, swap

I like to set-up two-or-three (k/l/x)ubuntu systems/partitions on a single drive (thereby failing the sanity test), with a swap partition (equal in size to the computer's RAM). The last-to-be-installed partition boots quickly, the other(s) are very slow to boot. I presume the penultimate partitions are slow to find swap or grub???

So, can anyone please suggest how to ensure boot-time won't lag. Perhaps the drive should be set up with swap as sda1? Perhaps the drive should be formatted as an extended partition (sda1), with swap as sda2? The slow-booting seems to occur when swap is created as the last (sda4) logical partition, or formatting sda4 as an extended partition, then making swap sda5.

Comment: Why do you install three different Ubuntu systems instead of installing the desktop-environments in one Ubuntu-installation. I think that would result in a much quicker boottime.

Comment: Kev Inski, thanks for teh suggestion - makes great sense.

Comment: Zanna - thanks for this. In my experience,  installing a distro via unetbootin or mutisystem, on an ssd, creates swap almost the same size as RAM.